# Is there a way to see the feature importance in deep learning (neural networks)?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, decision-trees, feature-selection

For tree methods, I can plot the feature importance plot from `tree.feature_importances_` in sklearn, is this achievable in deep learning (neural networks)?

Is there a way to see the feature importance in deep learning (neural networks)?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute this conceptually or are you asking for a library does it? If the latter, then this question is off-topic. If the former and the latter, then it's on-topic. If the former, it's on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In the current state, Deep learning for Tabular is not very popular, so it is very hard to find libraries that support feature importance. However, [TabNet](https://github.com/dreamquark-ai/tabnet) also provides the `model.features_importance_` metrics to be used as usual. [This Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/optimo/tabnet-with-loop-feature-engineering-explained#Basic-Features-importance) provides an example on how to use just that.